# Trouble joining contents of log files to single doc

Tags: powershell

I have log files stored in several sub-directories of a folder `D:\TILT_Logs`. I want to combine all of the files into one document, `D:\TILT_Logs\Combined.log`.

My current script appears to be skipping some of the files, but I am not sure why.

```
$combine = GCI 'D:\TILT_Logs' -Recurse -Filter '*.log'

Get-Content $combine.FullName | Set-Content 'D:\TILT_Logs\Combined.log'
```

When I open `Combined.log` it is missing data from some of the log files, but I cannot figure out why they are being skipped.

**EDIT - I also ran `echo $combine` to make sure that my GCI was addressing all the files and it is. All files are addressed by the GCI and are echoed, however only a small portion of the files are going into `Combined.log`

Some of the files that appear to have been skipped are

```
D:\TILT_Logs\Dec\12_29\Tilt.12892.2017_12_29.log
```

and

```
D:\TILT_Logs\March\3_6_Kutchey\Tilt.4740.2018_03_06.log
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you want to use `Add-Content` instead of `Set-Content`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Going to give that a whirl.

Comment: Getting the same results with that.

Comment: You can also pipe the output from `Get-ChildItem` directly to `Get-Content`.

Comment: Can you post some of the data that is missing?

Comment: @Garrett Are those files that are skipped in `$combine`?

Comment: Those files show up when I echo `$Combine` but the data in the file does not end up in Combined.log. In fact so little data shows up that i believe more files are 'skipped' than not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used the `Add-Content` commandlet it will append instead of replace

```
$combine = GCI 'D:\TILT_Logs' -Recurse -Filter '*.log'

Get-Content $combine.FullName | Add-Content 'D:\TILT_Logs\Combined.log'
```

**EDIT** Simplifying these commands into one line also will work, credit to Mathias R. Jessen

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\TILT_Logs' -Recurse -Filter '*.log' | Get-Content | Add-Content 'D:\TILT_Logs\Combined.log'
```